# PHP - SLIM API - howto share variables across multiple PHP files but request specific

Tags: php, slim

I have a server running a API using Slim.

Each API request points to PHP code / functions divided in different PHP files.
I'm not so heavy into PHP, and now I'm passing or setting variables in each class where needed.

I'm Wondering if there isn't a better way to set a REQUEST SCOPE 'global' variable that can be shared across the different PHP files? But are not shared between all the incoming request.

Should I:

- Work with Sessions?
- Work with a Singleton?
- ...

Code examples are difficult to give. 
This question fits more into a conceptual question.

Any good advice into accomplishing the sharing of variables across multiple PHP files, but with the REQUEST scope?

Comment: With request scope you mean data which is saved between requests from the same client?

Comment: Where each API call is a request. Since the API handles multiple requests for different applications. As an example each request send along a APIKEY. This APIKEY is a variable needed on multiple places along the code. Therefor looking for a neater way of accessing the value without the need of passing along this value in each class constructor / class setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that your PHP application is initiated for each incoming request, so there is no way you can "share" data between requests accidentaly. I now cannot think of a way to do it on purpose, really.

As for "sharing information" between different files: the information is actually shared. Here's an example:

```
project/
    test.php
    mew.php
```

Content of `test.php`:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
include 'mew.php';
```

Content of `mew.php`:

```
<?php
echo $foo; // accessing variable that was declared in "parent" file
```

Output of `GET project/test.php` request:

```
bar
```

So, you don't really have "sharing" problem.

**Edit**

From your comment I understand that you need some sort of client authentication. This can be done in many ways: from primitive and insecure authentication by IP address (using [this middleware](https://github.com/akrabat/rka-ip-address-middleware), for instance), classy HTTP authentication ([tool for that](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/tree/2.x)), JWT is a good method ([tool](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth/tree/2.x)).

Conceptually it is simple: every client's request must be followed with some sort of token. When you recieve a request, you grab that token, identify client by it and return appropriate response.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!!! :) So creating a Singleton (ex. RequestDataClass) - and setting the variables inside this Singleton would be a safe way? Each API request will initiate a new Singleton class, and not interfere with other request Singletons, correct?

Comment: What do you expect that `RequestDataClass` to contain?

Comment: General data wich is shared for that particular APICALL accross application logics.

Comment: Yes. The rule is: every request follows the same routine, requests cannot interfere.